# Trouble getting text after an element using xPath

Tags: php, xpath

First, sorry for my english.

After looking many topics regarding to my problem I didnt find anything to make my xPath works.

Here's the site I would like to extract data from : [mysite](http://wpp01.msss.gouv.qc.ca/appl/K10/public/formulaire/K10FormCons.asp?noForm=1423)

```
<td width="50%" valign="top">
    <span class="libelleLecture">Nom de la résidence&nbsp;:</span><br>
    La Maison du Soleil (Sylvie Paquette)
</td>
```

I would like to extract all info from the table named "Nom et coordonnées de la résidence"

For the first data (Nom de la résidence) I tried this xpath with no luck

```
//*[@id="pourImpression"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/text()
```

For some reason this return nothing while I try to echo it.

Then I tried

```
//*[@class="libelleLecture"]/following::br/text()
```

Nothing appears...

But when I try with `//*[@class="libelleLecture"]` I get all "data title" needed but without values

```
Nom de la résidence :
Code postal :
...
```

Anyone get an idea where's my misstake? Thanks.

EDIT

I can't get it working, html error 500. /following::br/following-sibling::text() seems to create the error. Any idea?

Here is my code :

```
$my_url = 'http://wpp01.msss.gouv.qc.ca/appl/K10/public/formulaire/K10FormCons.asp?noForm=1423';
$html = file_get_contents($my_url);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$my_xpath_query1 = '//*[@class="libelleLecture"]/following::br/following-sibling::text()';
$result_rows1 = $xpath->query($my_xpath_query1);

foreach ($result_rows1 as $result_object1){
    $nom = $result_object1->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo $nom."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building from your 2nd XPath, the target text nodes aren't child of `br` but siblings :

```
//*[@class="libelleLecture"]/following::br/following-sibling::text()
```

Result in Firefox's Firepath  :

[image]

Comment: Thanks har07 but I get a HTML ERROR 500 when I use Following or preceding. I added my code above.